# Group a table by a column and filter by another another column, remove row that has more than one occurrence of the filter across group

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this... BUt the groups and the contrasts are much longer than this but this is basically how the repetition continues, making the table unnecessarily long.

summary

[This much like the original dataset I am working on. The dataset is much bigger than what I can post here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTuJu.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c53sl.png)

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* with new data, trying to reconstruct the groups after `distinct`. If this is not the real data the approach might fail at any time because the requirements are asymmetric.

```
df %>% 
  distinct(Contrast, .keep_all=T) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(uniqCon = sum(unique(Contrast) == df$Contrast)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(uniqCon = min(uniqCon), 
         Group = LETTERS[which(LETTERS == Group[1]):
          (which(LETTERS == Group[1])+(uniqCon[1]-1))], .by = Group) %>% 
  select(-uniqCon)
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  Group Contrast
  <chr> <chr>   
1 A     X-Y     
2 B     X-Z     
3 C     Y-Z     
4 D     N-M     
5 D     R-S     
6 D     R-O     
7 E     X-S
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E"), Contrast = c("X-Y", "X-Z", 
"Y-Z", "X-Y", "X-Z", "Y-Z", "X-Y", "X-Z", "Y-Z", "N-M", "R-S", 
"R-O", "N-M", "R-S", "X-S")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

*old approach*

Something like this, using `cur_group_id()`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(Contrast = Contrast[cur_group_id()], .by = Group)
  Group Contrast
1     A      X-Y
2     B      X-Z
3     C      Y-Z
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, @Andre. This works for the scenario I described. However, I realized I my table is more complex than my example. This update captures it well

Comment: You are right. The code didn't work because it's not the exact dataset